# pathlib.Path(path).mkdir(), not creating directory

Tags: python, logging, mkdir, pathlib

I am trying to implement logging for my flask project on a virtual machine (running Ubuntu-16.04). I have the following function for creating a new directory.

```
def mkdir_p(path):
    try:
        pathlib.Path(path).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
    except FileExistsError as exc:
        raise
```

And the following file handler inheriting from RotatingFileHandler.

```
class MyRotatingFileHandler(RotatingFileHandler):
    def __init__(self, filename, mode='a', maxBytes=0, backupCount=0, encoding=None, delay=0):
        mkdir_p(os.path.dirname(filename))
        RotatingFileHandler.__init__(self, filename, mode, maxBytes, backupCount, encoding, delay)
```

This all works fine when registering a new logger at runtime, on my local machine, but when I try and run this same code on an azure instance, the path and file I am passing in ('log/error.log'), isn't created.

I have made sure the user running the code has write permissions set on the directory. I really can't think of any other reason why this might be happening though.

Comment: can you make sure, that MyRotatingFileHandler.__init__() is actually called?

Comment: why not use `os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(filename))` and what's with the redundant raise in mkdir_p?

Comment: Exception ```TypeError: mkdir() got an unexpected keyword argument 'exist_ok'``` was raised on Python3.4.4

Comment: @JoshuaNixon That arg is new with 3.5. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.mkdir

Comment: So it's probably a Good Idea to verify that azure is running 3.5, at least.

Comment: @wotanii I'm sure, it all works fine on my local machine, and I attach it to a logger instance. And yeah, I tried using os.makedirs as well but I got the same issue. Don't ask about the raise, just ignore it for now. Please.

Comment: @PM2Ring I have flask running through UWSGI, I also installed uwsgi-plugin-python3, here are two lines from the UWSGI startup output that might shed some light: 
`open("./python3_plugin.so"): No such file or directory [core/utils.c line 3721]
!!! UNABLE to load uWSGI plugin: ./python3_plugin.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory !!! ` 
`*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.17.1 (64bit) on [Mon Aug 20 17:10:23 2018] *** 
Python version: 3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01)  [GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
Python main interpreter initialized at 0x1d323f0
python threads support enabled `

Comment: @PM2Ring Verified that it is running Python 3.5, the error is because I added plugins=python3 into the uwsgi ini file, but installed it through pip (therefore, plugins are built into the uwsgi binary and that line is not required) removed it and it still works. This doesn't bring me any closer to a solution about the mkdir though.

Comment: Sorry, I'm almost out of ideas. And I don't know about azure, or UWSGI. But I still suspect that it's a permissions issue. Can your Python script create a simple file in that location?

Comment: @PM2Ring I made a script containing just the same Path.mkdir() function but with the path string hard-coded and it worked fine. I'm running UWSGI as the same user I ran the script as, who is also part of the group for all files and folders within the project, and has write permissions (`drwxrwxr-x 6 owner group  4096 Aug 20 17:43 app`)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178380/discussion-between-ebd-and-pm-2ring).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone it might help, the [following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48836470/uwsgi-flask-logging-config-not-working-and-also-breaks-application) link may provide some useful explanation, but in essence, when using external application server to serve your application (as opposed to the dedicated Flask runtime, Werkzeug) you need to make sure your logger definitions occur **before** you register your Flask app, as follows.

```
# add logger
logger = logging.getLogger('flask.app')
...
# register flask
app = Flask(__name__)

...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run("0.0.0.0", threaded=True)
```

> When you want to configure logging for your project, you should do it as soon as possible when the program starts. If app.logger is accessed before logging is configured, it will add a default handler. If possible, configure logging before creating the application object. - [Flask Docs - Logging](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/logging/)

I was using uWSGI to serve my application, but I was instantiating my logger after my Flask app, and inside the `if __name__ = '__main__':` blocks, which is why it worked fine in my local configuration but stopped working the minute I pushed it to production.